# Show indentation line in IntellIJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

There is a plugin in vim which shows you "dots" (or lines, etc.) where the indentation level is.

Example:

[image]

Is there something similar for IntellIJ IDEA?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Go to *Settings/Editor/General/Appearance* and select *Show vertical indent guides* to enable this feature in IntelliJ.

[image]

Comment: Enabling the guides also makes it popup a tooltip on the top if the cursor is on a column where the starting block is above the top displayed code line.
That popup slows down the editor a lot. I set the keyboard repeat rate to pretty fast (60 cps), because that way I can scroll up and down quickly without having to resort to using the mouse. But if the caret is at a column where it wants to display those popups, moving the caret up and own becomes very chunky. 
Is there a way to keep the guides on, but to make it not popup those tooltips along the top?

Comment: Now, it is shown as "Show indent guides" in PyCharm Professional 2018.2

Comment: Now it's "Show whitespaces", in the same location (for IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1)

Answer (score 8):

I believe you were looking for General > Appearance > Show Whitespaces. I had to follow that with adjusting the "Whitespaces" color because of using a dark theme.
[image: Seeking these dots you are]

Comment: yes, I had to first show whitespaces, then change the color of whitespaces to actually see it clearly