# IntelliJ indentation guides in Project explorer window

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to have indentation guides in the Project explorer window similar to [what is possible in the editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32350515/2031150)?  My multi-module Gradle project window has a huge amount of whitespace.  Even now when I'm pushing past 30 classes, it is difficult to determine what lies at what layer.  Eventually, I'll have 50 or even 100 classes, and it will only become more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance, **Show tree indent guides**:

[image: Show tree indent guides]