# vertical lines in PyCharm like in Visual Studio

Tags: pycharm

How to add such gray lines in PyCharm as in Visual Studio Code to mark the indentation levels?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Show indentation line in IntellIJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32350515/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearence
```

And check [`Show indent guides`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-editor-appearance.html):

[image]